# Is CLLocation distance calculation stateful? How do I work around this?

Tags: ios

I find that after calculating a distance of zero with [CLLocation distanceFromLocation:], subsequent non-zero distance calculations are different than before the zero-distance call. Is this true, and if so is there a workaround for getting consistent results?

This is currently running on "iPad Air - 12.1" simulator using Xcode 10.1.

````
NSLog(@"loc1 =%.20f %.20f", loc1.coordinate.longitude, loc1.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"loc2 =%.20f %.20f", loc2.coordinate.longitude, loc2.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"result1 = %.20f", [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2]);
NSLog(@"loc1 =%.20f %.20f", loc1.coordinate.longitude, loc1.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"loc2 =%.20f %.20f", loc2.coordinate.longitude, loc2.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"garbage = %.20f", [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc1]);
NSLog(@"loc1 =%.20f %.20f", loc1.coordinate.longitude, loc1.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"loc2 =%.20f %.20f", loc2.coordinate.longitude, loc2.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"result2 = %.20f", [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2]);
NSLog(@"loc1 =%.20f %.20f", loc1.coordinate.longitude, loc1.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"loc2 =%.20f %.20f", loc2.coordinate.longitude, loc2.coordinate.latitude);
return [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2] / CGFloat(US_NAUTICAL_MILE_TO_METRE);```
````

I would not expect to see result1 and result2 different in the output:

```
2019-05-24 14:12:06.361771-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc1 =-96.25799399999999650390 33.44624999999999914735
2019-05-24 14:12:06.361872-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc2 =-97.03769400000000189266 32.89723099999999789134
2019-05-24 14:12:06.362052-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] result1 = 94849.40430844188085757196
2019-05-24 14:12:06.362263-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc1 =-96.25799399999999650390 33.44624999999999914735
2019-05-24 14:12:06.362375-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc2 =-97.03769400000000189266 32.89723099999999789134
2019-05-24 14:12:06.362599-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] garbage = 0.00000000000000000000
2019-05-24 14:12:06.362776-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc1 =-96.25799399999999650390 33.44624999999999914735
2019-05-24 14:12:06.362899-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc2 =-97.03769400000000189266 32.89723099999999789134
2019-05-24 14:12:06.363118-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] result2 = 94676.80041732524114195257
2019-05-24 14:12:06.363339-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc1 =-96.25799399999999650390 33.44624999999999914735
2019-05-24 14:12:06.363574-0400 ... -[RouteParserRoute distanceInNauticalMilesFrom:to:] loc2 =-97.03769400000000189266 32.89723099999999789134
```

Comment: If you're relying on the location of the device for these calculations (through the `CLLocationManager`), realize that the location manager will often return a number of different coordinates over a span of time even when the device is still in an attempt to get the most accurate location possible. The device relies on a number of sensors (not just one) to pinpoint a coordinate.

Comment: Well, no, as you can see in the log, the coordinates are the same. The distance calculation result, however, is different.